# Converter CEP para latitude e longitude (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Preciso de uma api em Javascript que converta um CEP digitado em latitude e longitude, alguém sabe uma que eu possa usar de graça?

Comment: Você quer fazer essa conversão pra poder pesquisar a posição no google maps? Se for o caso, não seria mais fácil pesquisar no maps direto pelo CEP?

Comment: ja tentei isso, mas ele nao reconhece o CEP para adicionar um marcador

Comment: É que dai o código da API muda, tem um especifico para CEP. Utilize o guia da própria Google para isso [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start), digite o CEP e ele vai gerar um exemplo de código, só precisa ter a key do google para usar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode usar o [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) da api do google. 
Adicione a API do Google

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Depois é só passar o cep ou endereço para obter a latitude e longitude

```
var lat = '';
var lng = '';
var address = {cep} or {endereço};
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
     lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
  } else {
     alert("Não foi possivel obter localização: " + status);
  }
});
alert('Latitude: ' + lat + ' Logitude: ' + lng);
```

Comment: Agora em 2018 esse serviço é pago. Alguém ainda usa?

Answer (score 4):

**15 de Abril de 2019**

Acesse a URL abaixo:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SEU_CEP&key=SUA_API_KEY
```

Ela vai retornar um JSON contendo o endereço completo e latitude e longitude.

Para essa URL funcionar, você precisa ter uma conta no ***Google Developers Console*** e essa conta precisa ter um cartão de crédito cadastrado. O valor é de aproximadamente US$ 7,00 a cada 1.000 requisições.

A sua API_KEY tem que ter habilitada a ***Maps Javascript API*** e ***Geocode API***